# Как убрать из вывода отображения длины массива

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста, у меня есть массив как его вывести без отображения в консоли длины массива "(6)", чтобы только отображался массив на JavaScript.

```
(6) [9138673, 9081984, 9151860, 9142008, 9142010, 9142021]
```

Пример:

```
var massiv = [9138673, 9081984, 9151860, 9142008, 9142010, 9142021]
console.log(massiv.join(' ').split(' '))
```

Результат:

```
(6) [9138673, 9081984, 9151860, 9142008, 9142010, 9142021]
```

но как убрать (6) не могу понять, чтобы только отображалось:

```
[9138673, 9081984, 9151860, 9142008, 9142010, 9142021]
```

Comment: а зачем? чем он мешает?

Comment: а так........перепешите метод `log` у консоли....или организуйте свой метод вывода информации

Comment: Как это сделать? JavaScript не мой язык, я  обычно пишу на Python.

Comment: а зачем? чем он мешает?

Comment: есть данные которые мне нужны, но их можно получить только через JavaScript, но если выводит эти данные, то он выводит только (6) строчку длины массива, а не сам массив.

Comment: Какое отношение к этому имеет вывод console.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать собственную функцию

```js
const someArray = [235, 536, 47346, 732576]

function customArrayLog(arr) {
  const values = arr.join(', ')
  console.log(`[${values}]`)
}

customArrayLog(someArray)
```

Эта функция преобразует массив к строке, и выводит эту строку в консоль

---

---

---

**UPD по вашему комментарию под этим ответом**

для передачи функции как строки:

```js
arrayToLog = "[25, 55, 66, 223, 75]"
logArrayScript = "console.log(" + arrayToLog + ".join(', '))"

Selenium driver.execute_script(logArrayScript)
```

Но не знаю будет ли этот метод работать, проверьте. Если нет, удаляю этот апдейт

Может где-то нужно экранировать символы наподобие `'`, но это уже за вами )

Comment: метод рабочий, спасибо, но мне не подходит. нужно что то, чтобы в один запрос входил через драйвер Selenium driver.execute_script('console.info(massiv.join(' ').split(' '))')

Comment: @Дмитрий обновил ответ, проверьте. Если я правильно понял вам нужно передать строку, которая преобразуется в скрипт, и выведет лог массива?

Comment: Только что чуть подкорректировал код